# jQuery for parent select

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the background color of the select box when they click on the select box but can't find what is wrong. I thought it would be something like

```
$(this.parent).css('background','#fff');
```

```js
     $('select.flag').change(function(){
    
     var callid = $(this).data('callid');
     var flag = $(this).val();
    
           $.ajax({
               url: "/calls/update/flag",
               type: "POST",
               data: {flag: flag, callid : callid},
               success: function(result) {
    
                $(this.parent).css('background','#fff');
    
               },
               error: function() {
    
                   alert("Error. Please try again.");
               }
           });
    });
```

```html
    <div class="pure-g">
     <div class="pure-u-1-4">
      <select data-callid="2" class="flag" style="">
       <option value="flag">Flag</option>
      </select>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The value of `this` changes in the success **function**.

Comment: And `$(this.parent)` is not how to access a parent element

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  Take a look at the *context* option.  Or use a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the value of `this` changes within the success callback and is no longer the element the event originated from.  There are a few ways to fix this.

## Set the *context*

Providing the *context* option lets you specify to jQuery what the `this` should be within the callbacks.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/calls/update/flag",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    flag: flag,
    callid: callid
  },
  context: this,
  success: function(result) {
    $(this).parent().css('background', '#fff');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("Error. Please try again.");
  }
});
```

## Use a variable

You could also make your own variable to store it in that does not change.

```
var that = this;

$.ajax({
  url: "/calls/update/flag",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    flag: flag,
    callid: callid
  },
  success: function(result) {
    $(that).parent().css('background', '#fff');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("Error. Please try again.");
  }
});
```

## Use the already existing event

The event already has a reference to the element on it, so you do not have to create your own variable.

```
$('select.flag').change(function(e){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/calls/update/flag",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      flag: flag,
      callid: callid
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $(e.target).parent().css('background', '#fff');
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Error. Please try again.");
    }
  });
});
```